# how to append a handlebars template to a div with a certain id?

Tags: jquery, templates, each, handlebars.js

i have a simple template that i populate with some data then im trying to append it before one did, but it seems to stop working.

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/nsvT3/8/)

and the code:

```
<ul class="wall_message">
    <li id="168" class="msgid">
        <div id="commentbox2">
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- in this case the json will be added only before `commentbox2`-->
    <li id="168" class="msgid">
        <div id="commentbox3">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>




<script id="comment" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                {{#each this}}
                        <div class="commentsp">{{comment}}</div>
                {{/each}}
</script>


<script>

//right now this json has only one main key (5), but it could have more
var data = {"5":
            {"id":"2", "comment":"xxxxxxxx"}
           }

/initiate the template
var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#comment').html() );

// place the json data in the template. the template will iterate through
msg = template(data);

jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
    console.log(val.id)

    //find the div with commentbox2 and add the msg before
    $('div#commentbox'+val.id).before(msg);
});
</script>
```

im not sure what i am doing wrong in this case.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to resolv your problem.

Your Json seems not "handlebar-compatible" for me.
I have rewrited it with a root element, which will be used in the `{{#each}}` statement.

```
var data = { 
    'items': [
        {"id":"2", "comment": "xxxxxxxx"}, 
        {"id":"3", "comment": "yyyyyyy"}
    ]
};

var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#comment').html() );
var msg = template(data);

jQuery.each(data.items, function(i, val) { 
    $('div#commentbox'+val.id).before(msg);
});
```

See the complete demo here http://jsfiddle.net/nsvT3/11/

I hope it's what you want.

Comment: let me test it. i could add a root element as well. this might take a few minutes

Comment: please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/nsvT3/15/ .In this case one item.id.2 should go to commentbox2 and item.id.3 to commentbox3

Comment: maybe `msg = template(val);` should be inside the loop

Comment: looks ok. if i do a `console.log(msg);` inside the loop i can see the message, but in my webpage it comes blank. Do you think is the json format. in my case it comes back like this `{"items":{"id":"404","comment":"qwqwcqcqcqcqcqc"}}`

Comment: items must be an array `[]`, not an object `{}`. This array contains many objects.